# How to add a string in string.xml using Java code, in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

I have created two EditText objects in the Java code of My android application, as

```
final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

then on the onClick() event of a button, called a method with parameters as-

```
addStringToXmlFile(et1.getText(),et2.getText());
```

now in the definition of this method below, i have written-

```
private void addStringToXmlFile(Editable editable1,Editable editable2){
        String s1=new String();
        s1=editable1.toString();

        String s2=new String();
        s2=editable2.toString();
}
```

The problem is that, now i want to use these two String objects s1,s2, to make two entries in the `res/values/Strings.xml` file of the database, & I don't know how to do it.

please guide me further.

Comment: you can just do String s2 = editable2.toString();  you don't need to initialize the string before assigning it

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - an app's apk (including it's resources) can not be changed at runtime. I'm not entirely sure of all of the reasons why, but one obvious thing I can think of is that R.java needs to contain a reference to your String in order for you to access it, and this file is generated by the compiler when you create the APK.

If you need to persist a String across sessions, you should look into using one of several [data storage mechanisms](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) that Android provides, such as [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into using SharedPreferences to store your string values instead.

```
//Saving your strings
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("s1", s1);
editor.putString("s2", s2);
editor.commit();

//retrieving your strings from preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String s1 = prefs.getString("s1", ""); //empty string is the default value
String s2 = prefs.getString("s2", ""); //empty string is the default value
```